# VSCode setting zsh terminal as integrated profile does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am working in a remote ssh server, and before the July 2022 update my integrated terminal was working fine. After the update however, I find that it no longer works, but specifically only if I set it to zsh.

I have set the following settings up:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "/bin/zsh"
        },
        "zsh (2)": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/zsh"
        },
        "zsh (3)": {
            "path": "zsh"
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
```

And all zsh profiles do not work. It is only zsh that does not work; both bash and tmux (which opens up a zsh shell) work. (I did `which zsh` to confirm the paths, but I wanted to cover all bases, thus the three profiles).

The integrated terminal works in my local machine (which also runs zsh). I'm not sure what else to check, any help is appreciated.

Currently, my workaround is to set up `/bin/zsh` at the end of my `.bashrc` and set `bash` as my default, but I'd rather not do that in the long run.

EDIT:
Here is a picture of my terminal when I set the default to any of the zsh profiles:

[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKtDL.png)